# How to map encrypted DateOnly to text in PostgreS

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

In an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API, I need to store a C# `DateOnly` entity property in a PostgreSQL text column after encrypting using `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL` (8.0.2) and `EntityFrameworkCore.DataEncryption` (4.0.1).

I am using a value converter to convert the `DateOnly` to string before encryption:

```cs
public class DateToStringValueConverter : ToStringValueConverter<DateOnly?>
{
    public DateToStringValueConverter()
        : base(dateOnly => Format(dateOnly), stringValue => Parse(stringValue))
    { }

    private static DateOnly? Parse(string? stringValue) =>
        null == stringValue ? null : DateOnly.Parse(stringValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AllowTrailingWhite);

    private static string? Format(DateOnly? dateOnly) =>
        dateOnly?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Then I am mapping the column to "text" in the entity configuration:

```cs
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Claimant> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable("claimant").HasKey(k => k.Id);
    builder.Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("id");
    builder.Property(p => p.BirthDate).HasColumnName("birth_date").HasColumnType("text").IsEncrypted();
}
```

And the table is configured as:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.claimant 
(
    id varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    birth_date text NULL,
);
```

I'm getting an error

> Column 'birth_date' is of type date but expression is of type text

The database log shows that it is trying to insert the encrypted string in the column.

Then I tried removing the encryption and column mapping, and I still get the same error, but now the parameter being inserted is

```
@p1='1981-06-28T00:00:00.0000000Z' (DbType = DateTime)
```

[BirthDate object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZm3P.png)

Comment: The error message tells you that your table column is defined as a date, not text.

Comment: Thanks Frank. Right, but the DDL says it is text in the DB.

Comment: Check your database connection string, to make sure you're connected to the same database. The error message is pretty clear, that column is of type date.

Answer (score 1):

Frank was right, but the error was not on the table itself. It was on a corresponding history table that was being written by a trigger upon the insert, so I didn't notice it right away. The type on the history table column was still DATE.